# FeynCalc: FermionSpinSum problems with interference of diagrams

Tags: feyncalc

I encountered a problem in FeynCalc, where i wanted to calculate the $\sum_\text{spins}|\mathcal{M}|^2$ of a process and therefore need the function FermionSpinSum[ ] of FeynCalc.

I run:

```
 TESTM = SpinorUBar[l, m].ChiralityProjector[1].DiracSlash[l].ChiralityProjector[-1].SpinorV[k, m];

 STESTM = ComplexConjugate[TESTM].TESTM;

 STESTM2 = FermionSpinSum[STESTM] /. DiracTrace -> Tr //StandardForm
```

and  the output is

```
2 Pair[Momentum[k], Momentum[l]] Pair[Momentum[l], Momentum[l]]
```

which is perfectly fine.
The problem arises when i add another diagram of the same order to the matrix element

```
TESTM = SpinorUBar[l, m].ChiralityProjector[1].DiracSlash[l].ChiralityProjector[-1].SpinorV[k, m] + 
   SpinorUBar[k, m].ChiralityProjector[1].DiracSlash[l].ChiralityProjector[-1].SpinorV[l, m];

STESTM = ComplexConjugate[TESTM].TESTM;

STESTM2 = FermionSpinSum[STESTM] /. DiracTrace -> Tr // StandardForm
```

which generates the following output

```
(Spinor[-Momentum[k], m, 1].DiracGamma[6].DiracGamma[
     Momentum[l]].DiracGamma[7].Spinor[Momentum[l], m, 1] + 
   Spinor[-Momentum[l], m, 1].DiracGamma[6].DiracGamma[
     Momentum[l]].DiracGamma[7].Spinor[Momentum[k], m, 1]).(Spinor[
     Momentum[k], m, 1].DiracGamma[6].DiracGamma[
     Momentum[l]].DiracGamma[7].Spinor[-Momentum[l], m, 1] + 
   Spinor[Momentum[l], m, 1].DiracGamma[6].DiracGamma[
     Momentum[l]].DiracGamma[7].Spinor[-Momentum[k], m, 1])
```

This clearly cannot be correct, since it still contains $\gamma$-matrices and spinors, which should've been gone after FermionSpinSum[ ].

I'm confused, can anybody help me at this stage?

Comment: May I suggest directly contacting the developer and FeynCalc community by posting your question on the [FeynCalc forum](https://feyncalc.github.io/forum)? You'll very likely get a response from them.

Comment: I hope i didn't miss anything trivial here. I wrote a mail to them; thanks for encouraging me to do so. I will post any updates as answers here if i get any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Majorana fermions are not supported in the stable version, so `FermionSpinSum` cannot automatically reorder the chains to apply the summation formulas.

I've just added this functionality to the development version today, so there

```
TESTM = SpinorUBar[k, m].GA[6].GS[l].GA[7].SpinorV[l, m] + 
   SpinorUBar[l, m].GA[6].GS[l].GA[7].SpinorV[k, m];
STESTM = ComplexConjugate[TESTM] TESTM;
FermionSpinSum[STESTM] // DiracSimplify
```

just works yielding

```
-4 m^2 Pair[Momentum[l], Momentum[l]] + 
 4 Pair[Momentum[k], Momentum[l]] Pair[Momentum[l], Momentum[l]]
```

See https://www.feyncalc.org/forum/1458.html

Since it's a "brand new feautre", there might be some bugs lurking around, so sensible cross-checks of the results are a must.